# Como faço para repetir uma verificação de senha?

Tags: java

Estou aprendendo Java e resolvi fazer um programinha simples de login, mas queria que quando a senha desse errada ele pedisse novamente para eu colocar a senha mas não sei como fazer. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public class PasswordVer {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);

        String senha1;
        String senha2;
        
        System.out.println("Por favor crie uma nova senha:");
        senha1 = password.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Insira novamente a senha para login:");
        senha2 = password.nextLine();

        if(senha2.equals(senha1)){
            System.out.println("Você agora está logado.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Senha incorreta. Por favor tente novamente.");
        }

        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: @Solkarped, pelo que entendi o cara quer utilizar um `do..while` ou `while`.

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de implementar é utilizando um comando de repetição do..while.

Segue um exemplo, utilizando o seu código:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
    String senha1,senha2;

    System.out.println("Por favor crie uma nova senha:");
    senha1 = password.nextLine();

    do {
        System.out.println("Insira novamente a senha para login:");
        senha2 = password.nextLine();
        if (senha2.equals(senha1)) {
            System.out.println("Você agora está logado.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Senha incorreta. Por favor tente novamente.");
        }
    } while (!senha2.equals(senha1));
}
```

Como saber quando usar o `do..while`?

Devemos usar quando sabemos que para cumprir a tarefa é necessário haver `pelo menos uma repetição` do nosso trecho de código para tomar uma decisão. Que é o nosso caso. Repare também o condicional para sair do comando condicinal [`do while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). Queremos que o usuário fique respondendo em loop até que acerte a senha.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, era isto mesmo que eu precisava.